# Can I use SQL Server Licensed Version in AWS EC2

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2

We are having a Virtual Machine in AWS EC2 Instance type of t2.large (Windows Server 2019). Then we installed the SQL Server 2014 Evaluation edition 5 months before and used it for our web application hosted in IIS inside the VM.

Since it's going to end the evaluation period in the next 30 days, we are ready to buy the license for SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition. I have the following questions and everyone is providing different answers. So please someone provide the genuine answers.

1. After buying the license, can we install it in the VM as it is the same in our own windows server.
2. We are not using the RDS, it's just the EC2 windows instance vm only, so do we need to bring the Software Assurance.
3. Why we should not use our own license in the VM system. What's the reason behind that?
4. If we use that then will it affect the Compliance.

Please clarify.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about licencing, which is beyond the scope of [so]. You would be better talking to your vendor(s) about such matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. AWS has ["Bring-Your-Own-License"](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/mt/simplified-byol-experience-using-aws-license-manager/) service which is made exactly for your case.
2. It seems that you do. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/storage/attachments/96089-sql-server-2019-licensing-guide.pdf) they say:

> Beginning October 1, 2019, on-premises licenses purchased without Software Assurance and mobility rights
> can’t deployed with dedicated hosted cloud services offered by “Listed Providers.”

See https://aka.ms/outsourcerights as well

3. They say, you can save your money when using AMI with SQL because of flexible licensing, pricing etc. You should review the pricing, workloads and working schedule by yourself and decide what will be cheaper for you- to use AWS SQL AMI or to buy your own license from Microsoft and attach it to AWS.
4. AFAIK no. But you should discuss it with your Microsoft Partner from which you want to buy a license.